# How can i convert pdf file into xls through coding using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to convert pdf file into xls using vb.net. How can i do it? I don't want any third party software.

Answer (score 1):

Interpretting PDF with pure vb.net will be pretty ambitious task without 3rd party software. Especially if its any PDF. There are tools like GhostScript that can interpret PDF files to images and other formats, but not sure if that will help.

An idea might be to try and convert a PDF to Html, it may be easier to render html in an XLS file.

Comment: Totally agree. Generally speaking, _anything_ to PDF is a one way function. You can sometimes pull individual objects back out (a block of text, an image, etc) but to reconstruct the original document layout would really be a monumental task. You'd have to learn both the PDF format (specific to whatever version of PDF you're using as well as the software creating the PDF) as well as the Excel file format.